# Rspec 0 examples, 0 failures ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.1, nomethoderror

When I run 'rspec spec/models/behavior_spec.rb' I get the following error

```
Finished in 0.01035 seconds (files took 6.44 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures    
/Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `increment_open_transactions' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/database_cleaner-0.9.1/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/transaction.rb:13:in `start'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/database_cleaner-0.9.1/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:73:in `start'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/database_cleaner-0.9.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `block in start'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/database_cleaner-0.9.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `each'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/database_cleaner-0.9.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `start'
from /Users/NamNguyen/Documents/gomoment/rev1/spec/support/factory_girl.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:349:in `run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `block in run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `each'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:410:in `run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/NamNguyen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Here is my group test development section in the Gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end
```

Here is my behavior_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

Rspec.describe Behavior, :type => :model do
  describe ".match_all?" do
    it "should be true if pattern is nil" do
    end
  end
end
```

I've searched other posts about getting `0 example, 0 failures` but nothing that applies to this situation. Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Notice that your `factory_girl.rb` file is only file of yours on the stack trace. That would be a good place to start looking. The `0 examples` output is also evidence that you're not even getting to your first example before encountering a failure.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Thanks for pointing me to the 
>factory_girl.rb. I have a 
>config.before(:suite) block in there with 
>DatabaseCleaner.start and 
>FactoryGirl.lint. When I commented those two out my Rspec ran just fine. I have no idea why that made it worked. Do you know by chance? If not, no worries, you've helped plenty! Thanks again!

Comment: No, I don't know what specifically caused it, but I'd suggest you figure it out, starting with determining whether one of those by itself will cause the problem.